# Gazebo errors in robotic_arm_environment (ros2 foxy, ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: python, simulation, reinforcement-learning, ros2

My goal is to make the arm manipulator catch the target object through reinforcement learning through gazebo-based robot simulation.

My environment is ros2 foxy and ununtu 20.04

Sample code link: https://github.com/dvalenciar/robotic_arm_environment
Tutorial link: https://davidvalenciaredro.wixsite.com/my-site/services-7

To build the following environment, the link to install ros control disappeared, so I installed the foxy version of the controller from ros control master github.
ROS control link: https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control

Error code is

```
[ros2-5] ros2: error: argument Call `ros2 <command> -h` for more detailed usage.: invalid choice: 'control' (choose from 'action', 'bag', 'component', 'daemon', 'doctor', 'extension_points', 'extensions', 'interface', 'launch', 'lifecycle', 'multicast', 'node', 'param', 'pkg', 'run', 'security', 'service', 'topic', 'wtf')
[ERROR] [ros2-5]: process has died [pid 11830, exit code 2, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state start joint_trajectory_controller'].
[ros2-4] usage: ros2 [-h] Call `ros2 <command> -h` for more detailed usage. ...
[ros2-4] ros2: error: argument Call `ros2 <command> -h` for more detailed usage.: invalid choice: 'control' (choose from 'action', 'bag', 'component', 'daemon', 'doctor', 'extension_points', 'extensions', 'interface', 'launch', 'lifecycle', 'multicast', 'node', 'param', 'pkg', 'run', 'security', 'service', 'topic', 'wtf')
[ERROR] [ros2-4]: process has died [pid 11828, exit code 2, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state start joint_state_broadcaster'].
```

and warning in

```
[Wrn] [Event.cc:61] Warning: Deleting a connection right after creation. Make sure to save the ConnectionPtr from a Connect call
[gazebo-3]
```

What's the problem?

I want try to make arm manipulator robot simulation

Comment: When you say you have installed ros2 foxy controllers, what do you mean? It seems that you are using the following command: ros2 control (…) that doesn’t produce anything. Tipical valid keywords following ros2 are “run” and “launch”.